# Lasso with non-linear objective

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I have a non-linear objective function that I want to minimize considering some constraints in order to obtain a sparse solution (lasso type).

min f($\theta$)
s.t.
$\sum_i|\theta_i|\leq t$
$\theta_i \in [0,1]$

There are many lasso algorithms for linear objective functions with or without bound constraint, but I didn't find any lasso for non-linear problems with bound constraint.

Does anyone know how to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Is $f $ convex?

Comment: f is not convex

Comment: Am modifying my previous comment as I stated it wrong:  Looks like you can remove the absolute values in your constraint.  A Lagrange multplier method may help:  For $\mu\geq 0$ define: $$ \theta(\mu) = \arg\min_{\theta \in [0,1]^n}\left[ f(\theta) + \mu \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i\right]$$ where $\theta(\mu)$ may be nonunique.  If you can find a $\mu\geq 0$ and a $\theta(\mu)$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i(\mu)=t$, then $\theta(\mu)$ is optimal for the original problem.  This holds for arbitrary (possibly nonconvex) $f$ functions.

Comment: If such a $\mu^*$ exists, then it can usually be found quickly with a bisection search that zeros in on the best $\mu$ exponentially fast: If you have bracketing values of $\mu$, every iteration you know whether to increase or decrease $\mu$.

Comment: I have a solution with the lagrange multiplier method, but it is not sparse. I need some conditions so that I can drop some variables (i.e. set them to zero)...